# Temporal and frequency analysis of brain network to study autism disorders

Tags: neuroscience, fmri, brain, autism, analysis

I know it has shown in the literature that autism disorder affects brain network connectivity based on rs-fMRI data ([Plitt, Barnes, & Martin, 2015](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.nicl.2014.12.013)). They have local over-connectivity but long-distance underconnectivity.

Does ASD affect dynamic of brain networks, such that has an impact on the temporal analysis? What about its effect on frequency analysis?
I wanted to have a whole brain, multilayer brain network analysis of autism disorders and wanted to know which one is better to build my multilayer model based on.

**References**

Plitt, M., Barnes, K. A., & Martin, A. (2015). Functional connectivity classification of autism identifies highly predictive brain features but falls short of biomarker standards. NeuroImage: Clinical, 7, 359-366. 
doi: [10.1016/j.nicl.2014.12.013](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.nicl.2014.12.013)

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE. With *"autism disorder affects brain network connectivity based on rs-fMRI data. they have local over-connectivity"*  to help others reading, could you please provide references to back this up?  I am not in a pure neuroscience field but would be interested to read about this.  Plus, questions and answers with citations backing claims tend to get up-voted as good questions and answers.  For some tips, maybe you would like to read the site's [tour](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/tour) and [good question tips](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: if you want a special reference, can take a look at this paper:
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2213158214001983